# Define null as a lower case version of NULL? c++

Tags: c++, null, user-defined-types

Quick question here, I am not a huge fan of typing **NULL** always in *upper case* and I wanted to know if I could define a *lower case* version.

When I try to define it in the header file as:

```
#define null NULL;
```

it allows this line to be compiled but if I try and call **null** anywhere in my code I get a syntax error.

For example, if I write:

```
if(root == null){ /* Code here */}
```

Eclipse tells me that this is a syntax error and if I try and build my project I get this error:

[image: null error]

Is **NULL** a special case in which I would not be allowed to do this or am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: Are you using C++11 or later? ... :)

Comment: What error are you getting? Give us a small example.

Comment: I believe I am using c++11. Well I should be. Why do you ask?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Comment: In C++11, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon, or follow Bjarne Stroustrup's lead and just use 0.

Comment: No, don't just use 0.

Comment: Stroustrup: 'There is no need to us NULL' in any well-written C++ program'.

Comment: Your error is stating that a `)` was expected before the `;` in your define.  You're changing `if(root == null)` to `if(root == NULL;)`

Comment: In C++ use `0` not `NULL`. If you have C++11 then use `nullptr` for null pointers.

Comment: @EJP: Whats the benefit of writing `0` instead of `NULL`? (Except typing fewer letters). I'm asking out of pure curiosity - using `nullptr` was one of the first things I did when c++11 was finally published.

Comment: Straustrup said use `0` rather than `NULL` because `NULL` was defined differently in different `C` implementations. So when Straustrup made `C++` he simplified it by making it `0`. Ahh found a link: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null

Comment: @DieterLücking Actually when you are writing NULL so much it becomes time wasting to continually go from upper case to lower case. It is just for simplicity as I am already writing in lower case to begin with.

Comment: @Galik And I didnt know NULL ment 0. I always thought that NULL was this place in memory, not necessarily memory address 0, that you just set your pointers to say that it ment nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using a C++11 compiler, use `nullptr` and don't bother with the `#define`.

If you must use the `#define`, remove the `;` from the line.

```
#define null NULL
```

Comment: Why did they add nullptr to C++11 and not simply use null?

Comment: @JamesBedford, I do not follow the standardization process. I don't have an answer to that.

Answer (score 5):

The semicolon at the end of the line is wrong. The right

```
#define null NULL
```

Comment: When you #define null NULL; preprocessor replaces line
if (root == null)
with
if (root == NULL;)
and you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers already stated, your error was to write `#define null NULL;` instead of `#define null NULL`. And if you want to define `null`at all you should actually define it to be `nullptr`. Just guess, what `foo(NULL);` will call, if those functions are available:

```
void foo(int* param);
void foo(int param);
```

The answer is ***implementation dependent***[1], because `NULL` might either be `0` or `nullptr`, so this is actually ***non-portable*** code.

I also wanted to add, that in your example there is no need to test against NULL at all, as `if (root)` has the exact same effect.

[1] From the current Standard working draft (N4296 / 2014-11-19):

> 18.2 Types
>   [...]
>   3) The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10).194

and

> 4.10 Pointer conversions
>   1) A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t
>   .

Comment: You've got a typo on "impelementation", also I thought `NULL` was actually `#define`d as `0`, no?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz: Thanks for the catch. It was defined to `0` but at least in c++11 it could be both. I'll add the quote from the standard in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Why not instead use `nullptr`? That's lower-case *and* type-safe!